# Muting sound completely

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to **completely** mute **specific** sounds *(not all)*. Using /stopsound is a quite imperfect way of doing so, because then there's fractions of the *"muted"* sound(s) sometimes still *"slipping through"* causing them to not be completely muted. Does anyone know if it is possible to completely mute them, and if so, how?

*(Resourcepack may be used, as long as you can tell me how to remove/replace a sound already existing in the game)*

Edit: I need an explanation on what to do, I have searched for how to do sound files in resourcepacks, but I need to know how to **add** sounds (as in, I don't know what name to use for a specific sound in the game). I want all crossbow sounds, music and player sounds all to be muted. But in all 1.14 resourcepacks that I have found up until now, none have sound files for crossbows, usually none at all actually.

In short, I need to know **how** to name the sound files.

Comment: The "What do to" section of my answer is what you want. The link called "resource pack" lists all the sounds and locations in an expandable paragraph.

Comment: Fabian Röling, it is close, but it's not a complete answer. It answers on what the options are, but not on how to actually carry out this option. I know that making sounds silent works, but I don't know how to find and replace these sounds, or rather, how to name a sound in order for it to work. (for adding a sound in a resourcepack that has no sounds in it yet)

Comment: The Minecraft wiki tells you how to use resource packs. The location of course depends on what sound it is. The Minecraft wiki page of resource packs has a button that expands a gigantic list of all files that can possibly be in a resource pack.

Comment: Oh my, gigantic is definately a correct way to describe this. I have found it, thanks.